# Display single value Of FirstChild Elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml

Please, Help me Out Here
I Want to display the value of "email" from xml. my syntax works for now but it displays every value. i want to be able to display Individual (one) Values like

```
email: mail@mail.com


My scripts

var xml ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<MemResponse> 
<Phone>2554535</Phone> 
<Email>mail@mail</Email>
<Number>we75546654</Number>
 </MemResponse>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
foreach(XmlNode n in doc.DocumentElement)
{
  string q = n.FirstChild.InnerText;
  Response.Write(q);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("YOUR_XML_PATH");
XmlNodeList email_hd= doc.GetElementsByTagName("Email");
string email=email_hd[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: Hi @imsome1 tried your code but it returns " null reference exception". Thank for the response. Any other way to go about it?

Comment: I tried my code and it is working, please try my code instead of yours. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes through each node and writes the contents of that node.

It seems like you want to match on the node name, and only write the value if its name is "email".

If thats the case, inside of your for each, try something like:

```
if(n.Name == "Email") {
    string q = n.FirstChild.InnerText;
               Response.Write(q);
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use a node list.

```
NodeList nl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Email");
```

And write that.

When loading your XML Doc, use :

```
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it returns nothing. Thanks for your Response. Any or other way?

Comment: try q = n.InnerText for the foreach loop example, or nl[0].inner text.  I think it's trying to find the child of a node when we really want the inner text of that node.

Comment: i think it works if i paste the xml into loadxml method. but if the xml is returned from a server it does not display anything. am just thinking it does not GetElementByTagName. from when xml come from server. Thanks for your Response

Comment: It sounds like you need to parse the XML before you give it to the Load xml method. there should be several examples of how to do this in C# here. Let me know if you have issues finding one :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can select all element by tag name by GetElementsByTagName method.

Check this :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var myEmails = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Email");

        foreach (XmlNode mail in myEmails)
        {
            string mailText = mail.FirstChild.InnerText;
            Response.Write(mailText);
        }
```

I have got it from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think the problem i have is that the xml load comes from a web service and does not work when loaded in "doc.LoadXml(xml)" in my script. but if copy the XML String in  "doc.LoadXml("Raw xml String)" it works. Any suggestions on how to make it work with xml return from server/webservice?. Thanks for your Response

Comment: yes, you can use this method to get  strem from response "GetResponseStream" check this >>

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            xmlDoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
        }

Comment: you can check this about services return XML 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534080.aspx